# .NET Core 3.1: how can I pass in sorting and filter params value in Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have a .NET Core 3.1 API (EF with a pervasive database). I have found a nice article about pagination (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/generic-filter-sorting-grouping-and-paging-for-any-view-model-in-server-side)

But I can't fill in the values for the sorting or filter parameters in Swagger. How can I do that?

[image]

```
   [HttpGet]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync([FromQuery] PaginatedInputModel pageParameters)
    {
        var Response = await _afspraakService.GetAllAsync(pageParameters);
        return Ok(Response);
    }
```

Comment: What you mean about you couldn't modify the sort parameters? You could click the add object item to add the sort object to use to test it.

Comment: No, i can't fill sortorder, columnname. As you can see it's red... In Debugmode i see that the count of the sortingParams is 0.

Comment: How can i access the sortingparams in code?

Comment: Please post your controller code with annotations. How is the `SortingParams` parameter defined and annotated?

Comment: i have edited the question with the Controller method